# Topshelf service/app stuck at "Creating"

Tags: c#, topshelf

I'm trying to start up an instance of Topshelf. I've downloaded the binaries for v. 2.3 and extracted everything.

Then I've created an empty console application. I've changed the framework to `.NET 4.0 framework` and added the following code to my `static void Main()` method:

```
Host h = HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.Service< MyApp>(s =>
        {
            s.SetServiceName("Something");
            s.ConstructUsing(name => new MyApp());
            s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
            s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
        });

    x.RunAsLocalSystem();

    x.SetDescription("Something");
    x.SetDisplayName("Something");
    x.SetServiceName("Something");
});

h.Run();
```

The consoleapp runs as expected when I hit F5.

I then copied the bin/release output to a topshelf/services/test directory and run Topshelf.Host.exe. This is the result:
 [image: Topshelf console output]

If I point my browser to the dashboard, this is what I see:
[image: Topshelf dashboard]

The "test" service keeps saying "Creating" (waited for over 15 minutes).

What am I doing wrong? I've tried with multiple kind of console apps. If I call `install` on my console app, the app gets registered successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you remembered to name the config-file correctly. It seems like the config file must be named _exactly_ after the folder. So if the folder is test, the config-file must be test.config. Or opposite, if the config-file is "MyAssembly.dll.config" the folder must be called "MyAssembly.dll" (yes, including the .dll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link the Topshelf DLL into your console application, you should run your console application from the command line. From what I can see about, you're trying to use the Topshelf Host instead. Try running your console application and you should see it start your service correctly.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't want to run my console application manually. I was expecting Topshelf to handle that, listening to the /services directory for changes, letting me run multiple applications as Windows Service and so on. Isn't that the purpose with Topshelf, or? Thanks! :-)

Comment: One of the features Topshelf offers is the Shelving-feature. And this is the responsibility of the Topshelf.Host. This is what the poster is asking about and the possibility to run the service from the command-line is therefore irrelevant. I have exactly the same problem. It works standalone, but when I try to run it as a shelf, it bombs out.

Comment: Well, shelving is a broken feature, and it's removed from the 3.0 release. Too many issues running separate services in the same process space and the general lack of understanding of how to handle exceptions in threads. So we yanked it and simplified Topshelf to be the minimum feature set needed to create services easily (which was the original charter).